# How can I source the output from a Perl script?

Tags: perl, bash

I'm looking for a way to accomplish this in a single statement:

```
./perlscript.pl ./inputFile "some option" > temp.sh; source temp.sh; rm -f temp.sh
```

`temp.sh` does

```
export ENV_VAR="some value"
```

and after the above commands `echo $ENV_VAR` reports `some value`.

I've tried

```
./perlscript.pl ./inputFile "some option" | source /dev/stdin
```

and the script runs, but the `source` doesn't seem to have worked; `echo $ENV_VAR` shows nothing. I feel like this is very close, but I've run out of ideas.

Any ideas?

Comment: `source` is basically "read a file and eval it"; how about `eval "$(perl etc)"`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) like this:

```
source <(./perlscript.pl inputFile "some option")
```